# Как сохранить работу (вкл/выкл) расширение в браузере после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, расширения

Чтобы когда плагин включен все работало даже после перезагрузки страницы и отменял изменения после выключения

Код из background.js

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "eraser_on.png", tabId:tab.id});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"e.js"});
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "eraser.png", tabId:tab.id});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id);
    }
});
```

Код из manifest.json

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "eraser.png",
      "default_title": "Erases annoying elements."
   },
   "description": "Erases annoying elements.",
   "icons": {
      "128": "eraser.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Eraser",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab", "storage" ],
   "version": "1.0.5"
}
```

Код из e.js

```
document.getElementsByClassName('-rep')[0].innerText="+100500";
```

Comment: а если попробовать `"persistent": true` ? или вообще его убрать

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Вы про persistent из manifest? Ничего не меняется.

Comment: возможно что-то изменили, насколько я помню этот параметр выгружал скрипт из памяти, надо лезть в документацию. Или пойти путем сохранения последних данных состояния в `storage` - это скорее даже правильней.

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Зачем выгружать из памяти, когда по моему, он должен быть всегда подгружен

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Как это сделать со storage?

Comment: это по мнению кодера правильно, а по мнению юзера нет - браузе-строители идут на встречу юзеру.

Comment: кстати, только заметил - даже в манифесте уже стоит разрешение `storage`. Вот и сохранять там флаг `toggle` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Разобрался как сохранить значения true false, те плагин стоит значение true, но скрипт e.js при обновлении страницы все равно не выполняется

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Я так понял, что скрипт работает после того как его нажали, а во время перезагрузки страницы он в состоянии суперпозиции, те 1 и 0, и пока его не активируют или не дезактивируют он не будет работать

Comment: у меня раньше при `"persistent": true` скрипт `background` сохранял все переменные, кстати и сейчас должно работать вот описание https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background   | А почему `e.js` должен вообще работать после перезагрузки, если по коду не видно, кто его туда заинсертил. `chrome.tabs.executeScript` указан в коде только для клика.

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Плагин не работает после перезагрузки страницы. Даже если через localStorage записать значение нажатия. то после перезагрузки его будто не запускали

Comment: плагин это довольно размытое понятие, есть фоновый скрипт и скрипт контента, если не работает скрипт контента, то и реализация тут надо другая, совсем через другие события, а не через клик на иконку.

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg обычное расширение, userscript, chrome-extension. Я еще не разобрался. Это весь скрипт в 3 файлах. Больше файлов нет. Было бы логичным сделать основной скрипт, который работает постоянно и юзает состояние плагина. И другой, который выполняется при условии что плагин активирован. Всего 3 файла background.js - основной, сбсно сам manifest.json манифест, и выполняемый код, при условии что background.js нашел, что плагин активирован - e.js

Comment: скрипт контента(встраиваемый в страницу) это и есть `e.js`. Я так понял он не хочет работать, если да, то надо было это и указать в вопросе. Я то думал требуется запустить `background`

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Нет, сам `e.js` запускается, нужно только сделать так, чтобы включенный плагин был включен после перезагрузки страницы или выключенный был выключен поле перезагрузки - `background.js`

Comment: так я к этому и веду - когда включили кнопку `e.js` должен все время работать при перезгрузках, а при выкл он работать не должен, ТАК???

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg Это да, но значение нажатости у `background.js` то не сохраняется

Comment: наконец с вопросом хоть более менее понятно стало, надо было так и написать - Хочу кнопкой активировать/деактивировать скрипт который встраивается в страницу. Сейчас попробую что-нибудь вспомнить

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg я пытался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это только для примера, там многое нужно дорабатывать

Пока не удалил, тут весь пример для подключения https://yadi.sk/d/Nr-CSw4JjbLhvw

При активации кнопкой и последующих перезагрузках, будет вылазить такая шляпа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// Для примера будем подключать скрипт, только по принудительному разрешению
//  и только для тех вкладок, где оно уже было разрешено

// Tут храним вкладки
const tabs = [/* id */]

// Прослеживает за изменениями вкладок
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId) {
  // если скрипт уже был подключен
  if (tabs.includes(tabId)) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "on.png", tabId: tabId })
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "page.js" });
  }
  else {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "off.png", tabId: tabId })
  }
})

// Это отвечает за активацию
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  // если не было включено
  let ind = tabs.indexOf(tab.id)
  if (ind === -1) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "on.png", tabId: tab.id })
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "page.js" })
    // запоминаем
    tabs.push(tab.id)
  }
  else {
    tabs.splice(ind)
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "off.png", tabId: tab.id })
  }
})
```

Comment: Много ли у вас ушло времени, чтобы написать такой скрипт? Спасибо, то что я искал

Comment: @Максим Больше года ничего не писал для плагинов, но если заниматься постоянно - это не займет больше 5мин. --- Когда перезагружаем вкладку, скрипта контента уже нет. `onUpdated-событие ` говорит что на вкладке что-то изменилось, и мы проверяем - если код был подключен ранее, снова его туда инсертим. Выше отметил - такой код нельзя использовать в реальном приложении. Вкладка ничего не значит, если откроем новую вкладку с таким адресом - придется опять подключать скрипт. `Background.js` должен постоянно писать в память где мы дали доступ к плагину и определять досткп не по ид, а по url-адресам.

Comment: В моем случае это подходит